# Invalid syntax on "def getBoardCopy"

Tags: python

```
def getBoardCopy(board):
    #Make a duplicate of the board list and return it the duplicate.
    dupeBoard=[]

    for i in board:
        dupeBoard.append(i)

    return dupeBoard
```

This is just to set a duplicate of the board, but I keep getting invalid syntax error and I don't know why.

Comment: Hard to say, it's possibly coming from the previous line of code, before the snippet you have posted. What's the actual error? Is it reported on the actual line `def getBoardCopy(board):`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, works perfectly for me. The error is elsewhere in your code. Can you provide the exact error and more context?

Comment: BTW, the simple way to make a shallow copy is  `board[:]`

Comment: @roganjosh its an error on def not the actual function.

Comment: It could possibly be caused by mixing tabs and spaces. Can you ensure that you are using only tabs or only spaces?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that the syntax above your line is wrong.

Look at the lines immediately before and look for missing parenthesis, colons, brackets, quotation marks, anything that could leave an expression open.

You might have missed a colon here on the previous line:

```
(bo[9] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[1] == le)
```

You should instead write like this:

```
(bo[9] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[1] == le))
```